# How to write FLAC files in java

Tags: java, audio, wav, audio-streaming

I have a requirement to write FLAC files in java. Earlier I was writing the audio input into a WAV file and then converting it to FLAC file using a external converter

I was looking into JFlac to find any API through which I can write FLAC files. I found  that AudioFileFormat.TYPE in java supports only the following file formats - AIFC, AIFF, SND, AU, WAVE .

I would like to have a method where I can capture the audio from the microphone and, using an API such as Audiosystem.write, write it to a FLAC file instead of WAV file.

Please suggest a method or an API that can solve my problem.

Comment: Don't know whether JFlac supports encoding to FLAC.  At the [news page](http://jflac.sourceforge.net/news.html) they say "The encoder is not currently supported."

Maybe [javaflacencoder](http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/) could work?

Comment: an downloading it and will check up on it.. but i had a look at the javadocs and it says the encode function will encode teh given input wav file. is there no way to writ the raw data spoken from the microphone to flac format directly. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Never used javaflacencoder myself, but guessing you would use [FlacEncoder](http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/javadoc/javaFlacEncoder/FLACEncoder.html) class for starters, looks like you can feed it samples.  You might also have to write your own implementation of FLACOutputStream if you don't want output to go to file.

Comment: (This is a guess, by the way, based on my experiences with using the encoder FLAC) I don't think you can encode a constant audio stream to FLAC. I'm pretty sure that you have to convert from a source file. My assumption is based on the idea that FLAC needs a file to compress in the first place, and that when it de-compresses the original file is then re-created (much like zip, rar, 7z or tar works)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/files/) lib. Here is a simple example using version 0.2.3 (javaFlacEncoder-0.2.3-all.tar.gz). Extract the dowloaded file, and then import javaFlacEncoder-0.2.3.jar to your project. For more documentation, see [here](http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/javadoc/javaFlacEncoder/FLAC_FileEncoder.html):

```
package fr.telecomParisTech;
import java.io.File;
import javaFlacEncoder.FLAC_FileEncoder;
public class SoundConverter {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FLAC_FileEncoder flacEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder();
        File inputFile = new File("hello.wav");
        File outputFile = new File("hello.flac");

        flacEncoder.encode(inputFile, outputFile);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope you're looking from time to time into Stackoverflow. Do you know if javaFlacEncoder is also working an the Android environment.

Comment: No, I know only the above.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* write audio stream directly to a FLAC file with javaflacencoder:

```
AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, FLACFileWriter.FLAC, new File("E:\\temp.flac"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change sample rates,
use **ffmpeg**
like this
**ffmpeg -i sourcefile.wav -ar 16000 targetfile.flac**

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP is asking how to create a FLAC file in Java.