# Android - FLAC_FileEncoder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

All,

I was trying to follow the instructions on this post and asked a question in an answer area, but had it deleted.  I don't know how to add a follow along question to a post.  Does stackflow have away to do this? I thought it was important to have the original people who posted reply to it.

[How to write FLAC files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466698/how-to-write-flac-files-in-java)

Moving forward.

I used Eclipse to import the reference lib: Project->Properties->JavaBuildPath->AddExternalJars Navigated to the javaFlacEncoder-0.2.3.jar.

Unfortunately I'm getting this as the following error message: FLAC_FileEncoder cannot be resolved to a type

I thought that I followed the instructions to load an external jar. Eclipse was able to tell me to import the lib into the file (Which it added the code when selected).  Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Shouldn't the variables be there from the import.

Dl'd the sources from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaflacencoder/?source=dlp

There is a document guide that shows it should be there ( This is why I wanted to talk to the guy that posted the response).

Code:

```
import javaFlacEncoder.FLAC_FileEncoder;

.....

  private void convertWavToFlac(String wavFilename, String flacFilename) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      FLAC_FileEncoder flacEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder();   // <---- Error
      File inputFile = new File(wavFilename);
      File outputFile = new File(flacFilename);

      flacEncoder.encode(inputFile, outputFile);
      System.out.println("Converted Wave to Flac - Done");
  }
```

Comment: hi, do you meet the error:java.lang.VerifyError: javaFlacEncoder/FLAC_FileEncoder

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up figuring out that I needed to restart eclipse.  Mistakes that contributed to the error are while changing the manifest, plus building/cleaning, I added/removed files not through eclipse.  Eclipse didn't like this every much and must have been confused on what was linking the files too.

There were additional errors after the restart.  They are identified in the post below.
[Eclipse for android: Issues with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746973/eclipse-for-android-issues-with-r)